# What does "with a means of" mean?

Tags: idioms, conjunctions

Context example:

> Teaching simple massage methods to caregivers provides them with a
>   means of meaningful and structured interaction with their loved one,
>   in addition to a means of connecting with and supporting each other.

- What does "with a means of" mean?
- Is it a conjunction?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"A means of X" is equivalent to "A method for X" or "A way of doing X".

"With" here goes with "provide": X provides Y with Z = X makes Z available to Y.